# Laravel 8 - Find image url

Tags: laravel

I am using `Laravel Framework 8.68.0`.

I am having the following configuration in my `filesystems.php`:

```
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'public_collectible_img' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/collectibles_img'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/collectible/image',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

The following link works:

`http://localhost/myProject/public/storage/collectibles_img/0_test.jpg`

The following link does not work:

```
http://localhost/myProject/public/collectible/image/0_test.jpg
```

All my images are in the following folder:

[image]

Any suggestion why my second link does not work?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

The `filesystems.php` only affects Laravel's internal filesystem management (e.g. moving a file from within Laravel, saving an uploaded file, etc.), not the actual HTTP server which is what serves static files such as images. If you want to have a custom URL, you can either modify your web server's configuration (e.g. `.htaccess`), or create a Laravel route and controller to serve files from within Laravel. The latter approach will require that you map the requests to files yourself, and each request would have the overhead of loading PHP.

Alternatively, you could create a symlink from `public/storage/collectibles_img` to `public/collectible/image` (you would need to create the `collectible` folder first, then set up `collectible/image` as a symlink to `public/storage/collectibles_img`).